# AngularJS and Dreamfactory: $resource.save() not saving all the records in loop or in queue

Tags: json, angularjs, api, rest, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to save the data using $resource and for REST API using Dreamfactory. I do have seperate mysql table for multiple addresses as user might have multiple addresses.

I'm looping through multiple addresses and querying to the API but some how it doesn't store in sequence or split some of the data to store

Here is my code:

```
Members.save($scope.member,
            function () {
                //console.log('POST',arguments );
                console.log('POST', arguments[0].id);

                $scope.mid = arguments[0].id;

                if($scope.addresses)
                {
                    $.each($scope.addresses,function(k,v){
                        //alert(k+"=>"+v);
                        Members_address.save({"member_id":$scope.mid,"address":v},
                            function () {
                                alert(k+"=>"+v);
                                console.log('POST',arguments );
                            }, function () {
                                console.error('POST', arguments);
                            }
                        );
                    });  
                    window.location = "#/members";
                }else
                {
                    window.location = "#/members";   
                }

            }, function () {
                console.error('POST', arguments);
            }
        );
```

"Members" is factory to store data into members table and "Members_address" is a factory to store data in separate members_address table with member id.

It stores addresses but not in sequence and sometime it missed one of the address.

Here are the factories:
    App.factory('Members',['$resource',function ($resource) {
        return $resource('API_URL', null, {'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
    }])

```
App.factory('Members_address',['$resource',function ($resource) {
    return $resource('API_URL', null, {'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
}])
```

Comment: Can you post your two factories so we can see how they are set up?

Comment: @egregious Please check factories.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Check this example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itcutives/b48QE/) using `recursion`, I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  So, one fundamental thing is the thought process when you working with data like this (especially with DreamFactory).  You want to create a 'payload' of data to send to the server rather that trying to iteratively save records.  Make an array of the records of a specific type that you want to save and then push them up to the server.  In this case...you want to save a member(single object) and then addresses associated with that member(array of objects).  The process is 'send member record to server then on save success, if I have addresses, create address objects with member id and store them in an array and send to the server.  Then on address save success redirect.'

So here's the code I came up with.  Hope it helps you out.  Also, checkout [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) for redirecting as opposed to window.location.  And if your in need of the window object checkout [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24window).  And...try only to use jQuery inside of directives to do DOM manipulation.  AngularJS provides a lot of functionality for manipulating data.

```
// I'm assuming that your 'API_URL' contains the following information shown
// in this factory definition.
App.factory('Members', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('YOUR_DSP_URL/TABLE_NAME', null, {'update': { method:'PUT' } });
}]);

App.factory('Members_address', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('YOUR_DSP_URL/TABLE_NAME', null, {'update': { method:'PUT' } });
}]);


App.controller('SomeCtrl', ['Members', 'Members_address', '$scope', '$location', function(Members, Members_address, $scope, $location) {

    $scope.member = {}; // Member data object
    $scope.addresses = []; // Array of address strings

    // attach to UI button to trigger the save
    $scope.saveMember = function() {

       // Save the member
       Member.save($scope.member).then(

        // Handle Member save success
        function(result) {

            // Check for addresses
            if ($scope.addresses) {

                // Create a temporary var to hold our payload
                // to the server
                var payload = [];

                // Assemble address objects for insertion in db
                angular.forEach($scope.addresses, function (_string) {

                    // create a temporary var to hold our address
                    var tempAddressObject = {};

                    // add member id
                    tempAddressObject['member_id'] = $scope.member.id;

                    // add address
                    tempAddressObject['address'] = _string;

                    // store on temporary payload array;
                    payload.push(tempAddressObject);

                });

                // Check that we have some records in our payload
                if (payload.length > 0) {

                    // Send to the server
                    Members.address.save(payload).then(

                        // Handle Success
                        function(result) {

                            console.log(result);

                            // redirect
                            $location.url('/members');
                        },

                        // handle Error
                        function (reject) {

                            console.log(error);

                            // redirect
                            $location.url('/members');
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        },

        // Handle Member save error
        function(reject) {

            console.log(reject);
        }
      );
    }
}]);
```